# htacces if statement https redirect for one page

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, https

I've made a big mistake with a of my client's secure pages and relative navigation and now google has started indexing the site showing https in results and not the http version as it "breaks" the site.

I want to 301 redirect all pages except one, to the non https version in htaccess.

I'm trying to redirect every page except the /(language variable)/form.html back to http:// version but I'm running apache 2.2.26. I saw something similar to what I want below but I'm not running Apache 2.4 so I get a 500 error.

```
 RewriteEngine on
<If "%{HTTP_HOST} == 'www.canpujolet.com/^([a-z]{2})/form.html$'">
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}  off
RewriteRule  ^([a-z]{2})/form.html$  https://www.canpujolet.com/$1/form.html  [R=301,L,QSA]
</If>

<Else "%{HTTP_HOST} !== 'www.canpujolet.com/^([a-z]{2})/form.html$'">
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,QSA]
</Else>
```

Any help and advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/[a-z]{2}/form\.html
RewriteRule ^[a-z]{2}/form\.html$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule !^[a-z]{2}/form\.html$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NC]
```

Comment: ok sorry I should have mentioned that I already have another rewrite rule: RewriteRule ^([es]{2})/form.html?$ /form.php?lang=$1&page=contact [L] and with what you suggested they get redirected to: http://www.canpujolet.com/form.php?lang=es&page=contact

Sorry I'm a designer not a coder. I suppose it's because {REQUEST_URI} returns the php file and not my rewitten html page. I put your code after everyting.

Comment: You need to keep your rule **below** these suggested rules in .htaccess

Comment: Try that in a different browser. **Make sure these 301 rules are very first rules in your .htaccess**

Comment: tried in Firefox just now...same...here's the htaccess: http://www.canpujolet.com/temp.html

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, working perfectly now.